# TexturePacking with Libgdx -

Tags: java, textures, libgdx

My program packs a series of images and outputs them into an aste.png, and an aste.atlas.  My code for packing is as follows:

```
public void pack(){
    System.out.println("Packing should not be ordinarily called!  If you did not have explicit intentions of Packing, please check ImageAtlas constructor.");
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    settings.maxWidth = 512;
    settings.maxHeight = 512;
    TexturePacker2.process(settings, "E:/Files/Eclipse Projects/StarFighters/StarFighters-android/assets/sprites/" + name, 
            "E:/Files/Eclipse Projects/StarFighters/StarFighters-android/assets/sprites/", name.substring(0,4));
}
```

I will not need to pack EVERY time I run the program which is why I can get away with absolute file paths(I'll only pack when I'm running desktop and have added new images), however, I only used absolute file paths because I cannot figure out how to do it otherwise.  I am using the android assets folder.  (The desktop is linked to the android assets folder)  As I am running it from the desktop version, it's trying to goto the desktop path, when I need it to use the assets path, which Gdx.files.internal handles for me.  (This problem is not essential to the function of my program)

Once I have packed the images I do as follows:

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("sprites/aste.atlas"));
public Texture getTex(String imgname){
    return atlas.findRegion(imgname).getTexture();
}
```

I pass in "sma_a2" as the imgname when I try and getTex();

my assets/sprites/asteroids directory has the following images:
big_a1.png
big_a2.png
med_a1.png
med_a2.png
sma_a1.png
sma_a2.png
Which were all successfully packed into the aste.png and aste.atlas

My problem is, no matter what fname I pass in the image I receive is the entire aste.png

I also was curious as to why I would use a pack instead of just the images, as I start with images, and then pack them, only to get images again..

---

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **My solution:**

Using "getTexture" returns the entire image, and texture regions store basically a rectangle which represents the regoin of the packaged image that is the individual image.  So, basically drawing TextureRegions isn't much different then drawing Textures, so I just drew the TextureRegion.  In my case that involved adding to a superclass, so that it supported Textures, and TextureRegions in subclasses.  Subclasses specified whether to use Textures or TextureRegions using a boolean, and different SpriteBatch.draw() methods were called for each.

As for why to use them P.T. posted above as follows:

> The whole point of an atlas is that all of the textures you look up in
>   it are in the "same" texture, but at different regions within that
>   texture. This way you can "bind" one large texture in OpenGL (which is
>   somewhat expensive) and then render lots of different pieces out of
>   the texture.
>
> Most of the other APIs in Libgdx that take a Texture should also work
>   with a TextureRegion.

So sounds to me like it is more effcient/faster.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call `getTexture()` on the `TextureRegion` returned from `findRegion`.

The whole point of an atlas is that *all* of the textures you look up in it are in the "same" texture, but at different regions within that texture.  This way you can "bind" one large texture in OpenGL (which is somewhat expensive) and then render lots of different pieces out of the texture.

Most of the other APIs in Libgdx that take a `Texture` should also work with a `TextureRegion`.

Comment: Ok, then how do I use a Texture Region?

Comment: I have 2 classes(asteroid, and spaceship), one class uses a just a plain texture, and asteroid uses the textureatlas.  These classes share parents, so there is a "getTex" is used when drawing these objects, and it returns a texture.  I'm not sure how I should handle this.

Comment: I think I am going to add a boolean for usesTexRegion, and then, my program will have a getTexRegion as well, which will be called if that boolean is false.

Comment: You should put all your asteroids and your spaceship in the same texture atlas.  Your classes should all reference a `TextureRegion`. You should render them by passing them to `SpriteBatch.draw`.  Behind the scenes, the SpriteBatch will optimize the OpenGL calls, and only upload your texture once (no matter how many asteroids/spaceships you draw).